# Xcode debugger: why is summary in red color sometimes

Tags: xcode

Just wondering, when the text is red temporarily but still shows a valid output, what does red color mean?
after a few increments in steps, it turns to regular black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean in the variable display window then red indicates a variable for which the value changed in the last step.